# Progress bar always set to max

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have a service which sends a broadcast to an activity which shows list of items in 
a Grid . A particular grid item has an image and a progress bar which should update on the 
broadcast receiver. The activity is registered with the receiver and shows the log as well.

When the broadcast is send the receiver updates the image and can set the alpha of the image
as well but can not update the progress of the progress bar. The progress bar is always set 
to maximum  Following is the code in the receiver

---

```
View v = bookgrid.getChildAt(0);
ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.book_progress);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.book_image);
progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
rl.setAlpha((float) 0.2);
progress.setProgress(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you are trying to use 0-100 based progress. for that you have to set progressbar max to be of 100 first

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setMax(int)

change your code to

```
View v = bookgrid.getChildAt(0);
ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.book_progress);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.book_image);
progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
rl.setAlpha((float) 0.2);
progress.setMax(100);
progress.setProgress(30);
```

Comment: by default though progress bar max is 100.. you should also check if you have set it to something else in code